# Polyglot ImportError: cannot import name 'Locale' from 'icu'

Tags: polyglot, pyicu

I was trying to run the polyglot for my sentimental analysis. After a lot of struggling,, I successfully installed Polyglot and pyicu. However when I ran my program, it gave me this error, and I don't know how to fix it

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/siyizhou/Documents/2020Fall/COMMresearch/code2/Pos_Neg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from polyglot.text import Text
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polyglot/text.py", line 9, in <module>
    from polyglot.detect import Detector, Language
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polyglot/detect/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import Detector, Language
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polyglot/detect/base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from icu import Locale
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Locale' from 'icu' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site- 
    packages/icu/__init__.py)
    siyizhou@Siyis-MBP code2 % polyglot download sentiment.en
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/polyglot", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('polyglot==16.7.4', 'console_scripts', 'polyglot')())
    File "/usr/local/bin/polyglot", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/metadata.py", line 77, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
     File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/polyglot/__main__.py", line 16, in <module> from icu import Locale
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Locale' from 'icu' (/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/icu/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 18):

The problem is package dependency. Run the following commands in order:

1- `pip3 install pyicu`

2- `pip3 install pycld2`

3- `pip3 install morfessor`

That should work for your case. Also, for more detailed answers, check [this link](https://github.com/aboSamoor/polyglot/issues/10)

Comment: @HelenKapatsa why so?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on MacOSX with a version around 13 (M1 or other), you may need some extra steps beforehand to update the search paths:

1. Start by installing `pkg-config` and `icu4c`, necessary for `pyicu` to work:

   `brew install pkg-config icu4c`
2. Next, get the correct path to `icu4c` with the following command:

   `brew info icu4c`
3. You will get an output like this:

   ==> icu4c: stable 71.1 (bottled) [keg-only] C/C++ and Java libraries for Unicode and globalization https://icu.unicode.org/home /opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/71.1 (262 files, 76.8MB)   Poured from bottle on 2023-01-02 at 16:21:11 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/icu4c.rb License: ICU
   ==> Caveats icu4c is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, because macOS provides libicucore.dylib (but nothing else).

   If you need to have icu4c first in your PATH, run:
   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
   echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

   For compilers to find icu4c you may need to set:
   export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include"

   For pkg-config to find icu4c you may need to set:
   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"

   ==> Analytics install: 375,450 (30 days), 1,501,837 (90 days), 5,475,904 (365 days) install-on-request: 6,461 (30 days), 20,819 (90 days), 87,520 (365 days) build-error: 15 (30 days)

Look at the `export` sections, in this case, my path to `icu4c` is: `/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/`

4. Use this path you got to update the following commands:

   `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/bin:/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/sbin:$PATH"`

   `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig"`

   `export PYICU_INCLUDES=/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/include`

   `export PYICU_LFLAGS=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/58.2/lib`
5. You are now ready to follow the steps indicated by [@Berkay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11503139/berkay)

   - `pip install pyicu`
   - `pip install morfessor`
   - `pip install pycld2`